# add multiple texts to JTextPane, and not replace each text with another

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I can't really seem to find a question asking to add multiple texts to a JTextPane. Also, append doesn't work on JTextPane.

```
konsol = new JTextPane();
konsol.setText("something" + "\n");
```

This is what I've tried, but it only replaces the old text. What to do?

Comment: Well, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) give you a link to a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html). I am not quite sure what you want to achieve but you could simply concatenate strings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a similar way in past, i can share it with you :

```
class JTextPaneExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
        tp.setSize(250, 250);
        appendToPane(tp, "Hello Java,\n\n", Color.BLACK);
        appendToPane(tp, "Hello Suing,\n\n\n\n", Color.BLUE);
        appendToPane(tp, "Hello......,\n", Color.RED);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(tp);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void appendToPane(JTextPane tp, String txt, Color clr) {
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, clr);
        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Serif");
        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        int len = tp.getDocument().getLength();
        tp.setCaretPosition(len);
        tp.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        tp.replaceSelection(txt);
    }
}
```

The result is like so

[image: JTextPane multiple line]

Comment: You could also interact directly with the `Document`/`StyledDocument` which might be more efficent

Comment: new information thak you @MadProgrammer appreciate it